# How to position all alert messages in a particular position of the screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I have developed a Application where it contains so many Alert Messages and i want display All Alert messages in a particular position of the screen. I have tried the following code but it works for individual alert messages. Is there any way that i can apply for all the alert messages in my applications.

```
  myAlert = Alert.show('Hello World');
  PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myAlert);
  myAlert.x = 0;
  myAlert.y = 0;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think you can set the position of an `Alert` message in ActionScript. You should instead create your own component and display it with help of PopupManager. You'll then be able to position it where you want.

Instead y

Comment: Have a look at this post. Here you can control a lot of Alert's properties through the custom imlementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775163/increase-the-gap-between-the-buttons-of-alert-box-in-flex-3

Comment: @duTr Why wouldn't you be able to set the position of an Alert in ActionScript?  To ramesh reddy If the code you showed works; why not just remove the 'centerPopUp' and set the x and y values directly?  You can easily encapsulate that code into a method.  You can create it as a Static method or put it in some shared class to have easy access to it anywhere.

Comment: In my application there are lot of Alert messages, i don't want to set x and y properties individually, i want it to be happen globally. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to say this differently: "You can easily encapsulate that code into a method. You can create it as a Static method or put it in some shared class to have easy access to it anywhere".  If you encapsulate the creation and positioning of your Alert into a static method. instead of calling Alert.show() you can do MyClassWithStaticMethod.StaticMethodToCreateAlert().

Comment: @www-flextras.com My mistake, I went to fast. But the given example without the `PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myAlert);` statement doesn't work either on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Like www-flextras.com suggested, you can use a class like this where you put your logic in order to position your alert messages.

You need to wait for the `CREATION_COMPLETE` event before you can set the position of the alert. Note that you can also use `_alert.move(_nextX, _nextY)` in the following example.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.core.IFlexModuleFactory;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    public class MyAlertFactory
    {
        private static const MAX_WIDTH:uint = 320;
        private static const MAX_HEIGHT:uint = 280;

        private static var _nextX:int = 0;
        private static var _nextY:int = 0;

        public static function show(text:String, title:String = "",
                                    flags:uint = 4, parent:Sprite = null,
                                    closeHandler:Function = null,
                                    iconClass:Class = null,
                                    defaultButtonFlag:uint = 4,
                                    moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):Alert {

            var alert:Alert = Alert.show(text, title, flags, parent,
                closeHandler, iconClass, defaultButtonFlag, moduleFactory);
            alert.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleAlertCreation);

            return alert;
        }

        private static function handleAlertCreation(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            _nextX = (_nextX + 20) % MAX_WIDTH;
            _nextY = (_nextY + 15) % MAX_HEIGHT;

            var alert:Alert = Alert(event.currentTarget);
            alert.x = _nextX;
            alert.y = _nextY;
            alert.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleAlertCreation);
        }
}
```